# SQL Syntax Issue MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, vba

I'm having problems with the syntax: 
I transferred this from SQL Design View to VBA.  [area] is numeric.  I'm simply asking you guys to do a cursory review and tell me if anything Jumps out at you.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT 'VCAP0112' AS VCAP0112, VCAP0112.[RECV IND] AS OMU, VCAP0112.[LEGACY ACCT], Sum(VCAP0112.[1 to 30 Day]) AS [0 - 30], " _
        & "Sum(VCAP0112.[31 to 60 Day]) AS [31 - 60], Sum(VCAP0112.[61 to 90 Day]) AS [61 - 90], Sum(VCAP0112.[91 to 120 Day]) AS [91 -  120], " _ 
        & "Sum(VCAP0112.[Greater than 120]) AS [+120], Sum(VCAP0112.[Pmt Difference]) AS TOTAL " _
        & "FROM Urcrosswalk INNER JOIN VCAP0112 ON Urcrosswalk.[Legacy GL] = VCAP0112.[LEGACY ACCT] " _
        & "WHERE (((Left([VCAP0112].[area], 2))=80 Or (Left([VCAP0112].[area], 2))= 81)) " _
        & "GROUP BY 'VCAP0112', VCAP0112.[RECV IND], VCAP0112.[LEGACY ACCT] " _
        & "HAVING (((VCAP0112.[RECV IND])='O' Or (VCAP0112.[RECV IND])='M' Or (VCAP0112.[RECV IND])='U'));"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `DoCmd.RunSQL` with a plain `SELECT` query.

From the *DoCmd.RunSQL Method* help topic ...

> A string expression that's a valid SQL statement for an action query
>   or a data-definition query. It uses an INSERT INTO, DELETE,
>   SELECT...INTO, UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, CREATE
>   INDEX, or DROP INDEX statement. Include an IN clause if you want to
>   access another database.

If your intention is to view the results from that query in Datasheet View, create a saved query with its SQL.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSelect As String

strSelect = "SELECT ... blah, blah, blah"
Debug.Print strSelect '<- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("YourQueryNameHere", strSelect)
```

Then you can open the saved query with `DoCmd.OpenQuery` ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourQueryNameHere"
```

Comment: Thanxs @Hansup Sorry to bother.  I'll go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx - before asking next time.

Comment: No bother, John.  Good to see you again.  I don't understand why you would need to go to the web, though.  Can't you use Access' built-in help?

Comment: BTW, check out `Debug.Print AccessError(2342)` in the Immediate window.  The template text for that error message includes more detail which would have clarified the situation at the outset.  I don't know why the error dialog only showed you part of it.  But `AccessError()` is another useful tool to keep in your toolbox.  Regards.

Comment: While here at the Company, the built-in help isn't always helpful, so I usually disregard that feature.

Comment: Using Debug.Print AccessError(2342) gets the following in the immediate window: "A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement.@For example, an action query that appends records starts with INSERT INTO. A data-definition query that creates a table starts with CREATE TABLE.@@1@1@3698@1" - Thanxs

Comment: Your're welcome.  Yes, it would have been useful if the error dialog showed you more of that message.